# Does calling GetInstance on a Singleton lifetime mapping return the singleton or create a new instance?

Tags: .net, structuremap

I have the following mapping in `ObjectFactory.Initialize` method:

```
expression.For<IFoo>().Singleton()
                      .Use<SomeFoo>()
                      .Ctor<string>("url").Is(<fetch from config>)
                      .Ctor<string>("username").Is(<fetch from config>)
```

This ensures that my classes that have declared `IFoo` as a dependency always get the same instance.

However there is a scenario in my application where I need to simulate how the `SomeFoo` object behaves for a specific user. I create the dependency using `GetInstance` like so:

```
var args = new ExplicitArguments();
args.SetArg("url", <dynamic url>);
args.SetArg("user", <logged in user>);

ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFoo>(args);
```

I would hope that this call with specific arguments would construct a new object rather than return a reference to the singleton.

What happens in this case and why? What would it take for me to maintain the singleton for 90% of the cases but have a new instance created in the rare 10%?

Comment: Did you try for yourself? What are your observations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried this and found that each time I called `GetInstance` with `ExplicitArguments`, a new unique object was created. But each time I called `GetInstance` without any arguments, the singleton reference was returned.